# Can I customise the content of an Excel drop down box to mirror the colour of another variable cell?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, conditional-formatting, fontconfig

I hope someone can help me with this, I am creating an accounts spreadsheet where 'Sheet 1' contains a list of:

- All activities we will be billing against
- Activity budget
- Planned spend
- Actual spend
- Budget varience (I.e. money left to spend or will flag red if overspent)

Additionally I have a number of other tabs that relate to this spend; so each tab is relevant to a different department. This allows users to go straight into their department and allocate their spend against the correct 'activity' via a drop down list (this list mirrors the activity list shown in sheet 1).

What I was trying to do was ensure that if someone went into one of the other tabs and selected am 'activity' from the drop down list that had been flagged in the front sheet as an overspend that this turned the 'activity' title red. I.e. mirrored the front sheet activity title in terms of format.

I have created a basic version of the sheet which should make it much clearer; just not sure if I can upload it?

Comment: You cant upload files diretly no, you'll need to upload it somewhere and provide a link to it. If its a `Validation` list, then I don't believe you can style it. If its a `Combobox` then you might be able to do some customization.

Comment: Ah. I think it is a validation list. I have created it using the 'Data Validation' option.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot style the actual list, you can style the cell after the selection has been made. It might be possible with `Conditional Formatting` but I don't really get on with that so I've just used VBA instead.

[Example Worksheet](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10316127/style.xlsm)

My example has a `Validation List` in Cell `A1` which takes its list from the range `B1:B3`. The VBA code detects any change to cell `A1` and looks the colour up using a `VLookup` with the range `B1:C3`.

The example will not work in older versions of excel (2007+ will be fine) you just have to change the way the `Target.Interior` is modified, as older versions don't know what most of that stuff is.

[image: picture of example worksheet]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Color As String

    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Color = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("A1"), Range("B1:C3"), 2, False)
        Select Case Color
        Case "Red"
            With Target.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 255
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Case "Blue"
            With Target.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
               .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 12611584
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Case "Green"
            With Target.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 5296274
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

You could also (or instead) just change the list item depending on weather its over-budget.

eg: `Cakes` vs `!!CAKES!!`

It's not quite as pretty but fairly simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified example is:

[image: SO15434119 example]

where it happens the values in Sheet1!E are computed.

Sheet1!A1:E7 is a range of Workbook scope named Awarning.

Sheet2!C2:C7 happens to be the range containing the list used for validation.

Conditional formatting has been applied to Sheet2!A2:A7 with a New Rule..., Use a formula to determine which cells to format, Format values where this formula is true: of:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Awarning,5,0)<0
```

and red fill.